Given the sets $X:(x+1)^2 + y^2 \leq 4, x^2+y^2 \ge 1$ and $Y:1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$. Is X homeomorphic to Y?
I'm trying to prove they aren't via connectedness.
I figured the point (1,0) is an important point (cut point) in this problem, but i think that X without (1,0) is still connected.

you are on the right track, the notion that is helpful here is simply connectedness

Your approach could be completed without using homotopy and simply connectedness, and just by using connectedness that you mentioned. Did you figure out something new?

I figured i could do it this way: Suppose there exists $h:X->Y$ homeomorphism, then we can choose a small enough $\epsilon$  so $B((1,0), \epsilon ) \cap X \subset X^{+}$ which is open and we will call U. We have that h(U) = V which is open and connected (Because U is), then $h(U\backslash {(0,1)}) = V\backslash f((0,1))$, but $U\backslash {(0,1)}$ is not connected, and $V\backslash f((0,1))$ is, so h cannot be an homeomorphism.

I'm not sure what you meant by $X^+$, but other than that, yes, this is what I also had in mind. As you mentioned, we just need to take the epsilon small enough to ensure when we remove the point $(0,1)$ from it, it becomes disconnected, and argue as you continued.

Also feel free to post your solution as an answer below here, so that the question gets settled.
